# Greenplum login issue

Tags: greenplum

We have different user in our environment(Greenplum/ Version 4.2.x)

(1. dbauser - User having DBA rights, can create objects and grant accss to other users

2. etluser - User having DML access and perform DMLs through Informatica
3. analyticsuser - having readonly access
4. bouser - user having readonly access and configured at BO reports to report on DB)

We are facing a problem for the last 3-4 days. Any of the user is not able to login to database through pgadmin except dbauser; when other users (etluser,analyticsuser,bouser) try to login the pgAdmin hanged and no response.

Comment: What do you see in GPDB logs? What is inside of pg_hba.conf?

Answer (score 0):

you can check the log in greenplum and most of the time you will the reason there.
Login to the server where your master is installed and go the directory of your master configured. Here is one example

/data1/data/master/gpseg-1/pg_log

Answer (score 0):

can you check the resource queue limit  and also priority of your user . some time DB exhaust with many connections

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472/169503) sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) referencing this one if it will help provide context.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the  resource queue limit for the respective user and also find the limited number of connections for that queue.